# React not rendering long list of strings

Tags: reactjs, sockets, react-hooks, websocket, swr

I have a long array in React, over 600 items of strings. I have a map function that lists these strings in a log. When I update the empty list to add all the strings, the update is fairly immediate but the HTML itself takes forever to update/doesn't update at all. It's only when I change the code and trigger some sort of fast reload does the HTML update, other than that it's unresponsive.

My original suspicion was that the list wasn't rendering because the list was overly long, but after trying it with a test list of just 2 or 3 items, it still didn't work. Now I think it's due to the fact that I'm fetching the items in a list through a WebSocket.

```
  const [logs, pushLogs] = useReducer(
    (prev, next) => {
      prev.push(...next);

      return prev;
    },
    ["Initializing..."]
  );
  useSWRSubscription(
    `ws://${host}/api/users/logs?id=${props.id}`,
    (key, { next }) => {
      const socket = new WebSocket(key);
      socket.addEventListener("message", ({ data }) => {
        pushLogs(data.split("\n"));

        if (data.includes("Finished")) {
          return () => socket.close();
        }

        return next(null, data);
      });
      socket.addEventListener("error", (event) => next(event.error));
      return () => socket.close();
    }
  );
```

I'm using SWR to fetch the logs and the reducer hook is just a state array that I can push to more easily. SWR is the NextJS (my stack) recommended way to fetch things but for the most part it's just an ordinary WebSocket. I map the `logs` array like this.

```
{logs.map((log, index) => {
  return (
    <span
      key={index}
    >
      {log}
    </span>
  );
})}
```

How can I use the WebSocket to get immediate updates to my array?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is you're [mutating](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push#description) the Array by using push. Since the Array is still the same object React doesn't know it has changed. React compares by reference and not by value.

From the [React docs](https://react.dev/learn/updating-arrays-in-state#adding-to-an-array), here is how you add to an Array in a way that React can see:

> push() will mutate an array, which you don’t want...
>
> Instead, create a new array which contains the existing items and a
> new item at the end. There are multiple ways to do this, but the
> easiest one is to use the ... array spread syntax

Comment: I'm using the useReducer hook though. I might be wrong but from what I see I am creating a new array no?

Comment: @rabbibillclinton This hook doesn't anything magically different than any other hook - or the same code at any other place at all. It won't create a new object at some hidden place in React's engine.

Comment: If you're having trouble understanding why Array.prototype.push works exactly the same every place you use it, you might be better off using Immer to allow you to work without needing to understand it.